# how to track crashes report from ios8 extension app?

Tags: ios8, crash-reports, ios-app-extension, crashlytics

I've tried Crashlytics, it doesn't seem to work, crash from container app works but crash from keyboard extension doesn't send out any reports. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ezimet I'm talking about crash report when it's live, not debugging.

Comment: So you are saying crash reports nothing do to with debugging?? I know what you are talking about, there is an answer on that question that says you can access the system log by simulator. I thought it would be helpful. Just ignore my comment.

Comment: @woof were you able to find any way to find crashes in extensions?I am in same boat too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

https://getsentry.com/welcome/